# Need to do a reset component backened in joomla - joomla in a subdirectory (CiviCRM)

Tags: joomla, civicrm

According to docs, I should run this command to reset some of my CiviCRM stuff in Joomla:

/administrator/index2.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1

However, we only used the Joomla & CiviCRM solution for our interal-business-facing side, and it's on a subdirectory of the main site.

//

However, whenever I run

//jovicrm/administrator/index2.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1

it goes to the main website

.

Considering the public-facing side is wordpress based and doesn't accept joomla browser commands, fortunately it just goes to the main site. My question is, what do I need to do to alter the browser address to make it reach joomla's subdirectory instead of root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're in a version of CiviCRM from the past couple of years, don't worry about entering the URL: it's in the menu.  Go within CiviCRM to Administer > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and Update Paths.

That menu item should correspond to:
http://yoursite.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1

Once you're there, you can check the paths and URL and hit Save to reset them.  You can also go there to clear all the caches with the Cleanup Caches button.

Now, if you just moved the site from somewhere, there's the chance that the web server doesn't have permission to write/delete in the template cache, so you might need to go into your files and clear out:

- everything within yoursiteroot/media/civicrm/templates_c (but not templates_c itself)
- the file yoursiteroot/media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/Config.IDS.ini